# Python: Iterate through and compare 2 lists of tuples element-wise

Tags: python, list, tuples

I've been struggling for hours and can't work it out, so please help me! I have 2 lists of lists that contain some tuples.

```
list_1 = [[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('an', 'DT'), ('apple', 'NN')], [('This', 'DT'), ('Should', 'MD'), ('be', 'VB'), ('taught', 'VBN'), ('at','IN'), ('school', 'NN')], [('you', 'PRP'), ('might', 'MD'), ('take', 'VB'), ('them', 'PRP')]]

list_2 = [[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBN'), ('an', 'DT'), ('apple', 'NNS')], [('This', 'DT'), ('Should', 'VB'), ('be', 'VB'), ('taught', 'VBN'), ('at','IN'), ('school', 'NNP')], [('you', 'PRP'), ('might', 'MD'), ('take', 'VB'), ('them', 'PRP')]]
```

I want to compare each tuple of each sentence in `list_1` and `list_2` element-wise, and return only the tuples that have different tags.

```html
def get_similarity():
        for list_1_sentence, list_2_sentence in zip(list_1, list_2):
            if len(list_1) != len(list_2):
                try:
                    raise Exception('this is an exception, some tags are missing')
                except Exception as error:
                    print('caught this error : ', repr(error))
            else:
                return [(x, y) for x, y in zip(list_1_sentence, list_2_sentence) if x != y]
                
get_similarity()
```

The problem is that it returns the different tuples but for the first sentence only:

```
[(('is', 'VBZ), ('is', 'VBN)), ('apple', 'NN'), ('apple', 'NNS'))]
```

Why doesn't iterate through all the sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
list_1 = [[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('an', 'DT'), ('apple', 'NN')], [('This', 'DT'), ('Should', 'MD'), ('be', 'VB'), ('taught', 'VBN'), ('at','IN'), ('school', 'NN')], [('you', 'PRP'), ('might', 'MD'), ('take', 'VB'), ('them', 'PRP')]]

list_2 = [[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBN'), ('an', 'DT'), ('apple', 'NNS')], [('This', 'DT'), ('Should', 'VB'), ('be', 'VB'), ('taught', 'VBN'), ('at','IN'), ('school', 'NNP')], [('you', 'PRP'), ('might', 'MD'), ('take', 'VB'), ('them', 'PRP')]]
final_tags = list(filter(lambda x:x, [[c for c, d in zip(a, b) if c[-1] != d[-1]] for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2)]))
```

Output:

```
[[('is', 'VBZ'), ('apple', 'NN')], [('Should', 'MD'), ('school', 'NN')]]
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach cause later on I want to find similarity percentage between the sentences and their tags. So, returning only one time the different tag is more convenient.

Comment: That's an interesting approach but probably one of the least readable ways possible. Golfiest way, so +1 :P

Answer (score 3):

## `return` exits the loop prematurely

The loop is only run once because you `return` the value on the first iteration. Instead, track all your results and return at the end of the function, like so:

```
def get_similarity():
    results = []
    for list_1_sentence, list_2_sentence in zip(list_1, list_2):
        # ...
        results.append([(x, y) for x, y in zip(list_1_sentence, list_2_sentence) if x != y])
    return results
```

You should see that this works. [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##rVKxboMwEN35iutkLLE03SJlqdKhQ1HURB0aocilF7BqbGQbKfTnKcaQhJAqUtWTB97z3Tu/O8ra5ko@NI3gxu7uYQHbbUg2OTckArLcEBpBSDx6e3z3kMnzS1aWAh0Rx4QmEVypX@eqEp@OeVl65gO9okeWVVluPRP3qi0kzz0waa6UGPeoVeWI1evK5xS8lxhaWPY1bpJjcaxIkiDoLM9uWI5vWF7f9jw84O@eV/9n@hP3kKHdGV5wwTS3dUjnAfSxVxr8n7AzKC3KFCNPzI4EcAnfvAx93nB9JuKC70Gg7HMo3C1O8DLVhdX1lHShGTcIT4cUS8uVdIa4gfYwCTiwERhVIFiWtbxGKLgxXGaETiR9yUkPmAHUWunr3UvNpQ1J2q0KutZdNsyhHarGUocdpuNOKAxOBTXaSst2i4cIatqN2n2Nx/n72Kmb6cFNsk4m2oF/6eViadP8AA)

Answer (score 2):

You return from the first iteration of your loop. But you can easily turn it into a generator by yielding instead of returning:

```
def get_similarity():
    for list_1_sentence, list_2_sentence in zip(list_1, list_2):
        #...
        yield [(x, y) for x, y in zip(list_1_sentence, list_2_sentence) if x != y]

list(get_similarity())
```